# How do I run a controller method by clicking a button in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a shopping cart in a view, and when I press the submit button on a form, I would like to clear the shopping cart array of its items.

The clear method is in MyCart.cs

```
public void Clear() => Lines.Clear();
```

The cshtml is

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Credit Card</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Fake Credit Cart Information">
</div>
<br />
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="">Check Out</button></a>
```

But whenever I run anything for the onclick, it says it cannot convert a null to an object. I don't know how to fix this error.

Edit:

My lines is in MyCart.cs

```
public class MyCart
{
    public List<CartLine> Lines { get; set; } = new List<CartLine>();

    public void AddItem(Item item, int quantity)
    {
        this.Lines.Add(new CartLine
        {
            Item = item,
            Quantity = quantity
        });
    }

    public void RemoveLine(Item item) =>
        Lines.RemoveAll(l => l.Item.Product == item.Product);

    //public decimal ComputeTotalValue() =>
    //Lines.Sum(e => e.Item.Product.Price * e.Product.Quantity);

    public void Clear() => Lines.Clear();
}

public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineID { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Which is referenced in my CartController.cs

```
public class CartController : Controller
{
    public MyCart myCart { get; set; }

    public CartController()
    {
        if (myCart == null)
            myCart = new MyCart();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myCart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<MyCart>("mycart") ?? this.myCart;
        ViewBag.myCart = myCart;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Buy(Product productToPurchase)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(productToPurchase);

        this.myCart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<MyCart>("mycart") ?? this.myCart;

        if (this.myCart.Lines.Count == 0)
        {
            var newItem = new Item
            {
                Product = productToPurchase,
                Quantity = 1
            };

            var newCartLine = new CartLine
            {
                Item = newItem,
                Quantity = 1
            };

            this.myCart.Lines.Add(newCartLine);
        }
        else
        {

            var quantityAdd = false;

            foreach (CartLine cartLine in this.myCart.Lines)
            {
                if (cartLine.Item.Product.Id.Equals(productToPurchase.Id))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cartLine.Item.Quantity);

                    var quantity = cartLine.Quantity += 1;
                    quantityAdd = true;
                }
                    
            }
            if(quantityAdd == false)
            {
                var newItem = new Item
                {
                    Product = productToPurchase,
                    Quantity = 1
                };

                var newCartLine = new CartLine
                {
                    Item = newItem,
                    Quantity = 1
                };

                this.myCart.Lines.Add(newCartLine);
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Session.SetJson("mycart", this.myCart);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Remove(string id)
    {
        myCart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<MyCart>("mycart") ?? new MyCart();
        int index = isExist(id);
        myCart.RemoveLine(id);
        HttpContext.Session.SetJson("mycart", myCart);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    private int isExist(string id)
    {
        return 1;
        //List<Item> cart = myCart;
        //for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
        //    if (cart[i].Product.Id.Equals(id))
        //        return i;
        //return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code ? I need to see more about your `Lines` object.

Comment: What was in the onclick="" before you removed it ?

Comment: I tried to do @ViewBag.myCart.Clear()

Comment: Did you mean `Check Out` button  onclick event?

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I am really new to .net

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I run a controller method by clicking a button in a view?

Actually, calling controller method from your view is quite straight forward. If you use [Form Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0) by calling [asp-action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-form-action-tag-helper) you could simply invoke your method.

Lets assume you have following controller method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Remove(CartItem item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
            //Calling another function
            RemoveItemFromCart(item);

            return View("Index");
        }
        public void RemoveItemFromCart(CartItem item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your function has executed item: {item.ItemName}");
        }

    }
```

Thefore, you can call it from your view as following:

```
<div>
    <form asp-action="Remove">
        <input asp-for="@Model.ItemName" class="form-control" value="MyValue" hidden />
        <input type="submit" value="Remove" class="btn btn-warning" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

However, based on your scenario, it seems your issue is something else. You want to clear your shopping cart item once you click the checkout button. If that is the case, you can try below steps.

Checkout Controller:

```
 public IActionResult CheckOut()
        {
            //Do Check out stuff here


            //Clear your shopping cart once checkout stuff done
            RemoveAllItemFromCart();

            return View("Index");
        }
```

Method which would remove cart item:

```
public void RemoveAllItemFromCart()
        {
            var cart = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexObjectSession<ShoppingCartObject>("ShoppingCart");
            if (cart != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in new List<CartItem>(cart.CartItems))
                {
                    cart!.CartItems!.Remove(item);
                    HttpContext.Session.SetComplexObjectSession("ShoppingCart", item);
                }
            }
           
           
           
        }
```

Seession Extension Class:

```
public static class SessionExtension
    {
        //setting session
        public static void SetComplexObjectSession(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        //getting session
        public static T? GetComplexObjectSession<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

Invoke from view:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form asp-action="CheckOut">
          <input type="submit" value="Check Out" class="btn btn-success" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you need more details, than you can have look at the [complete example here.](https://github.com/kironiitdu/ShoppingCartApp/blob/master/ShoppingCartApp/Controllers/ShoppingCartController.cs#L68)